# image gradient angle computation

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing, gradient

I am actually following the instructions of a paper:

[image]

The input is supposed to be a binary "edge" image. The output should be a new image, modified by the instructions in the paper. My understanding of the instructions is, that one takes the gradient image of the edge image and modifies it and creates a new image with the modified gradient. Therefore is there a possibility in MATLAB/OpenCV of creating the same image with a new gradient?

Reference to the paper: 
Li, Hongyu, and Lei Chen. "Removal of false positive in object detection with contour-based classifiers." ICIP. 2010.

Comment: Care to put a reference to the paper in here, for the sake of completeness?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The formula displayed, I suppose, converts the gradient orientation form radians to pixel intensity ranging from 0 to 255 (standard for many images format). In matlab, if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can get the image gradient direction as follows:

```
[Gmag, Gdir]=imgradient(YourImage);
```

Now, as said in [the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient.html), `Gdir` contains angles in degrees within the range [-180 180]. If you wish to have them in the [0 255] range to follow what is in this paper, do as the formula says:

```
GdirI=(Gdir+180)*(255/360);
```

You can also display an angle plot in its original format using `imagesc(Gdir)`.

Comment: Great answer, and I second the request for a reference.

Comment: Do I get a badge for a compliment from @chappjc? :-)

Comment: Just my vote. :) But I give out tons of those without comment, believe it or not!

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do I safe the same image with the new gradient?

Comment: @user3236180 you're welcome. Check the `imwrite` function: www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html

Comment: I cant see there how I can specify the gradient?

Comment: @user3236180 You have a variable `GdirI` with the transformed gradient from my code and a function `imwrite`that writes images to files. Now read the docs and use your common sense :-)

Comment: For me a gradient is just an attribute/character of an image. You are saying now, that I should save the modified gradient as a representative of the old image with the modified gradient. But how can this be?

Comment: @user3236180 I'm not sure of what you are after. The image gradient is an image itself. I will need to look into the paper more in details.

Comment: @Jigg It's actually just page 2 of the paper:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=05649943